# i have data from controller taht return json . but i cant render to html if the data dosent exitst

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

i have data from controoler that return as json and when i render to html its work while data is exist , but if data dosent exist the else steatment dosent work . so i want if data is true data rendered else render htm like

## data not found

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pePoq.png)

```
here is the controller
  public function index_get()
    {
        $tanggal = $this->get('tanggal');
        $id_anggota_keliling = $this->get('id_anggota_keliling');
        $trip = $this->trip->get_data_trip($tanggal,$id_anggota_keliling);

        if($trip){
            $this->response( [
              // array ini bisa digunakan untuk pengkondisian di frondend
                'status' => true,
                'message' => 'data ditemukan',
                'data'  => $trip,
                'total_data' => count($trip)
            ], RESTCONTROLLER::HTTP_OK );
          }else{
            $this->response( [
                'status' => false,
                'message' => 'ko',
            ], RESTCONTROLLER::HTTP_NOT_FOUND );
          }
    }


view_trip.php 


<script>
function get_trip(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url('trip') ?>',
            type: 'GET',
            data :{
                'id_anggota_keliling':$('#anggota').val(),
                'tanggal':$('#tanggal').val()
            },
            success: function(results){                
                console.log(results.status);
                if(results.status == true){
                    console.log(results.status);
                    let data = '<tbody><thead><tr><th scope="col">Trip ke</th> <th `enter code here`scope="col">Jumlah Galon</th><th scope="col">Jumlah Kupon</th> <th s`enter code here`cope="col">Jumlah Uang</th><th scope="col">Edit</th></tr></thead>'
                    for(i = 0 ; i<results.data.length;i ++){
                        data += '<tr> <td>'+results.data[i].trip_ke+'</td>';
                        data += '<td>'+results.data[i].jumlah_galon+'</td>';
                        data += '<td>'+results.data[i].jumlah_kupon+'</td>';
                        data += '<td>'+results.data[i].jumlah_uang+'</td>';
                        data += '<td><button class="btn btn-primary" on`enter code here`click="edit_trip('+results.data[i].id_trip+')">Edit</button></td></tr>';
                    }
                    data += '</tbody>';
                    $('#table').html(data);
                }else{
                    $('#table').remove();
                }
                             
            }
        })   
    }

</script>
```

Comment: jQuery will not call the `success` callback, when you make the server respond with an error status code (which you are doing, with `RESTCONTROLLER::HTTP_NOT_FOUND`.) You will either need to respond with a normal 200 OK in this case - or add an `error` handler to your AJAX code.

Comment: thanks that's very usefull , i use error handling and work as i want. but i still curious why this cannot only use success:function .....

error: function (results) {
                if(results.status == 404){
                    $('#table tbody tr').remove();
                    $('#tidak_ada').remove()
                    $('#tidak_ada').html('Tidak ada data');
                }
            }

Comment: your ajax success returns a string not a boolean, so just try: `if(results.status !== 'false')` instead of `(results.status == true)`. that should do it... Please add the error message as text instead as an image, see: [**Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2275490)

Comment: _"but i still curious why this cannot only use success:function"_ - as I said, responding with a 404 status code is preventing that. If you respond with `RESTCONTROLLER::HTTP_OK` in the error case as well, then you will be able to handle both in your success callback.